# SQL server GEOGRAPHY STDistance function is returning big difference than other test results

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, distance, latitude-longitude, sqlgeography

I am calculating distance in meters between two lat long values - 
40.1844441 -77.2252771 and

40.319166 -76.7880552

I tested the distance between these two points in below two web sites - 
http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml and
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Both of these web sites return approximately 40014 meters.

So, I uses SQL server's GEOGRAPHY data type to calculate the distance between these two points again and it returns 48927 meters. It is a huge difference to me.

Below is my code and any suggestion is appreciated.

```
declare @latlong1 GEOGRAPHY
declare @latlong2 GEOGRAPHY
DECLARE @distance float

set @latlong1 = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(40.1844441 -77.2252771)', 4326)
set @latlong2 = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(40.319166 -76.7880552)', 4326)

SET @distance = @latlong1.STDistance(@latlong2)
SELECT @distance -- this returns 48927 meters
```

Answer (score 2):

I too have noticed some odd results, so I tend to use **geography::Point()** which seems to generate cleaner results.  Even then, option 2 is 80 meters off from the UDF which seems to be spot-on.

**Example**

```
declare @latlong1 GEOGRAPHY
declare @latlong2 GEOGRAPHY

Set @latlong1 = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(40.1844441 -77.2252771)',4326)
Set @latlong2 = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(40.319166  -76.7880552)',4326)

Select VeryOdd = @latlong1.STDistance(@latlong2)
      ,SQLGeo  = geography::Point(40.1844441, -77.2252771, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(40.319166,-76.7880552, 4326)) 
      ,UDFGeo  = [dbo].[udf-Geo-Meters](40.1844441,-77.2252771,40.319166,-76.7880552)
```

**Returns**

```
VeryOdd             SQLGeo              UDFGeo
48927.1485292471    40093.8055001913    40014.8833526855
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-Geo-Meters](@Lat1 FLOAT, @Lng1 FLOAT, @Lat2 FLOAT, @Lng2 FLOAT)
Returns Float as
Begin
    Return ACOS(SIN(PI()*@Lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@Lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@Lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@Lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@Lng2/180.0-PI()*@Lng1/180.0)) * 6371008.8
    -- 6.371 mean radius of earth in meters
End
```

Comment: John C: I can confirm your UDFGEO result is correct to 12 significant figures, based on the earth being a sphere of radius 6371008.8 metres.

Comment: @JohnMachin Thanks for the extra effort and confirmation

Comment: @JohnCappelletti -  thank you.
I also confirmed using "Spherical Law of Cosines" which is exactly the you have calculated and it returns 40014.8833526855 meters. Yes. I used globe's radius as 6371008.8.

Comment: using mean value of semi major axis and semi minor axis of WGS84 ellipsoid you can get more closer results, so try using R=6367444.6

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the lat and lon in the "VeryOdd" case i.e. use `POINT(-77.2252771 40.1844441)` and `POINT(-76.7880552 40.319166)`.

My offline "spherical law of cosines" result is 48733 metres which is only about 0.4% difference from the original VeryOdd 48927 metres.

I suggest trying a few more tests with different lats and lons, plus checking the docs for the relevant functions/methods.

Late breaking news: **STGeomFromText('POINT(*longitude latitude*)'** etc -- compared with the more frequent protocol: latitude first then longitude

See the selected answer to this question:
[Create Geometry/Geography Field from Latitude & Longitude fields (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551963/create-geometry-geography-field-from-latitude-longitude-fields-sql-server)

To clear up the remaining differences, somebody needs to search for what radius/radii is/are invoked by the `4326` magic ...

Comment: using mean value of semi major axis and semi minor axis of WGS84 ellipsoid you can get more closer results, so try using R=6367444.6