# Unable to convert column in SSMS to data type geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssms, geography

I currently have a task where I need to compare distances of latitude and longitude for specific locations and I have an Excel spreadsheet that has lots of data on latitude and longitude and need to convert those data type into `geography`.

The problem is, before finding out the distances, I need to convert the columns to `geography`. I tried using import wizard to SSMS but unfortunately, I do not have the option to change the data type to geography. Putting the data type to `decimal` and trying to change manually will give of an error:

> Explicit conversion from data type decimal to Test.sys.geography is not allowed.

I thought of creating a table manually but the problem is the number of rows that the latitude and longitude have is HUGE.

Please assist me on the ways I could do to convert the column to `geography`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new column named GeoLocation which will convert the lat long columns to geography. Perhaps you can create this column as computed column though.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Your Table Name]
ADD [GeoLocation] GEOGRAPHY
```

Then update this column using the following SQL query

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Your Table Name]
SET [GeoLocation] = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
                    CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
```

More details can be found at this link
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Import you Excel spreadsheet as a working table, then, make a [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that [transform to geometry you decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

Take a look here could help you :

[Create Geometry/Geography Field from Latitude & Longitude fields (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33551963/5546267)

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, correct me if I'm wrong, basically what I should do is just import the excel to the SSMS, making the lat and longitude to decimal. From there, I should combine insert into select with the query that Juan Carlos Oropeza user has posted?

Comment: @Zafear yes, that was that, but I see Kalyan already give you the SQL (with update instead on insert into select, but that's the same).